# I’m trying to count the number of rows from multiple .RDS files in R

Tags: r

I have multiple files all named specifically for a species ie. salmon, trout, etc. I am trying to condense down to only having files that have 200 or more rows(results). To do this I need to be able to count the rows for all files and remove any that have less than 200. The datasets cannot be added together as they are different data sets. And there are to many to files to code individually. 
Please help I am very new to R.

Comment: Welcome! In order for this community to better assist you, please provide us with a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also, take a moment to read over [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you!

Comment: You can import them to a list with `lapply()` and then also use `lapply()` with `nrow()` to find out which have less than 200.

Comment: are you able to use the `word count ` bash command? try running `shell("wc --help")` in R what happens?